# How create application backend in django and create a api so that other developers can use that as well

Tags: django, reactjs, rest, django-rest-framework, backend

I just started learning Django and wanted to make an application with API (probably REST) endpoints so that other developers can use it as well (like GitHub API), and I could connect it to my react app and android app. I want my backend to be on a different server and do not want to build my react app integrated with Django backend using the REST Framework.

Can anyone just give me the general idea of what I need to do?

P.S. Sorry in advance if my question sounds silly, I am still new to backend.

Answer (score 1):

Creating a Django REST API should be your first step. This is pretty simple if you already have a Django app running, and will allow your React app or Android app to connect and access data.

Authentication is a step beyond. You may want to look into implementing authentication on the server you will be hosting your back end on. You can also read through [this article](https://sunscrapers.com/blog/django-rest-framework-login-and-authentication/) for some guidance on implementing auth on the DRF side.

Best of luck!

Answer (score 0):

First off all you can start from this.
https://www.django-rest-framework.org/tutorial/quickstart/